# Using Ajax/JQuery filled dropdown, would like to dynamically change UI without another server side call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax post method that populates a dropdown.  Right now I'm returning the description of the object but would also like to update a textbox with the selection's ID. Everytime I change the selection I would like this textbox to change to the corresponding ID and description without performing an AJAX method. 
Here's the code:

```
function fillCheckRunDD() {
$.ajax({
    url: './PayInvoicesWS.asmx/GetCheckRuns',
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        var checkRunData = data.d;

        $crid = ("#CheckRunID");
        $crid.val(checkRunData.CheckRunID);
        $dd = $("#check_run_dropdown");

        $.each(checkRunData, function (index, value) {
            $dd.append("<option value='" + value.CheckRunID + "'>" + value.Description + "</option>");
        });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        sendErrorEmail(window.location.href, 'FillCheckRunDD', XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

}

Here's the .change function - right now it updates just the description.  I can't figure out how to display it's ID in a textbox.

```
$("#check_run_dropdown")
                .change(function () {
                    var optionChange = $('#check_run_dropdown option:selected').text();
                    $('#CheckRunDescription').val(optionChange);
                    $('#CheckRunDescription').prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#vendor_payment_type").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#vendor").prop("disabled", false);

                });
```

This is the initial server side code that populates the dropdown.

```
 public static IEnumerable<CheckRun> GetCheckRuns()
    {
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("GetCheckRuns()"))
        using (var context = rempscoDataContext.CreateReadOnlyContext())
        {
            return (
                from cr in context.check_runs
                where cr.check_run_approval_status == 1
                select new CheckRun

                {
                    CheckRunID = cr.check_run_id,
                    Description = cr.description,
                    CheckRunApprovalStatus = cr.check_run_approval_status
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Here's also a little screenshot of what I'm trying to do as well.
[image]

I appreciate any help with this.  Thank you.

Comment: not part of your question but in your success code your appending the options to the doms select element referenced in `$dd`. I believe for speeds sake you should build a non dom select element and append to that before adding the contents to the dom.

Comment: Non-element selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.val()` on a select box to get the value of the selected option so assuming you have a text box named `CheckRunId` you can do this -

```
$("#check_run_dropdown").change(function () {
    var optionChange = $('#check_run_dropdown option:selected').text();
    $('#CheckRunDescription').val(optionChange);
    $('#CheckRunId').val($(this).val());
    $('#CheckRunDescription').prop("disabled", false);
    $("#vendor_payment_type").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#vendor").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

It might also be a good idea to change this -

```
var optionChange = $('#check_run_dropdown option:selected').text();
```

to -

```
var optionChange = $('option:selected', this).text();
```

which will look for a selected option in the changed `this`.

If you want to re-use the original array you could save the array to a global variable -

```
var checkRunData;

function fillCheckRunDD() {
$.ajax({
    url: './PayInvoicesWS.asmx/GetCheckRuns',
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        checkRunData = data.d;

        $crid = ("#CheckRunID");
        $crid.val(checkRunData.CheckRunID);
        $dd = $("#check_run_dropdown");

        $.each(checkRunData, function (index, value) {
            $dd.append("<option value='" + value.CheckRunID + "'>" + value.Description + "</option>");
        });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        sendErrorEmail(window.location.href, 'FillCheckRunDD', XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

Then you can access it in your change function like so -

```
$("#check_run_dropdown").change(function () {
    var optionChange = $('option:selected', this).index();
    $('#CheckRunDescription').val(checkRunData[optionChange].Description);
    $('#CheckRunId').val(checkRunData[optionChange].CheckRunId);
    $('#CheckRunDescription').prop("disabled", false);
    $("#vendor_payment_type").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#vendor").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply. The CheckRunID textbox  is where I want the ID of the option that is selected to go.  Currently I can update this textbox with the correct ID of the selection on page load, but when I change it, it doesn't update.  I just figured since I was getting back an array of objects with their id's from the initial page load that I could somehow persist that to updating the CheckRunID textbox when changing the dropdown selection.  Should I just do another ajax call in that change method?

Comment: @Crumblenautjs Ok, if you want to re-use the array I've added a bit extra that should work, though it's untested.